# Adding a 'target' attribute to the URL of a tabstrip item in Telerik MVC extensions

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-mvc

I am replacing this 'hand-rolled' tabstrip with the Telerik Extensions Tabstrip below it, but I can't fathom how to get the Tabstrip to include the `target` attribute in the URL for each item. How can I achieve this?

Before:

```
<ol>
    @foreach (var sheet in Model.Sheets)
    {
        <li>
            <a href="@(Url.Content(Server.MapUrl(sheet.FilePath)) + "?guid=" + Guid.NewGuid())" target="selected-worksheet">@sheet.Name</a></li>
    }
</ol>
```

After:

```
@Html.Telerik().TabStrip().Name("Card").BindTo(Model.Sheets, (item, tabInfo) =>
    {
        item.Text = tabInfo.Name;
        item.Url = Url.Content(Server.MapUrl(tabInfo.FilePath));
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`LinkHtmlAttributes`](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/p_telerik_web_mvc_ui_navigationitem_1_linkhtmlattributes.html) property to set additional html attributes:

```
item.LinkHtmlAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "target", "selected-worksheet" }
};
```

Actually I've never used Telerik, so I am not quite sure if you have to instantiate a new dictionary or simply add a key (in case the property is automatically instantiated):

```
item.LinkHtmlAttributes["target"] = "selected-worksheet";
```

Comment: `LinkHtmlAttributes` is a read-only property. There is a `Template` property, but it isn't documented for the TabStripItem.

Comment: @ProfK, indeed, it has a private setter, then the second code snippet should work.

Comment: Eish, sorry, I overlooked that. I ended up cheating with jQuery, hehe.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had a similar problem with the Telerik TreeView and solved it via a detour with jQuery.

My problem was, that it didn't work to pass any (Link)HtmlAttributes, to the TreeViewItems in the View. I tried to add several HtmlAttributes to the TreeViewItem in the Controller: (e.g. one attribute I wanted to add to the  *< a >*  element):

```
 newNodes[i].HtmlAttributes.Add("data-ajax-update","#main");
```

, but after *return* as *JsonResult* of the Ajax-Request, all except *.Text, .Value, .Enabled, .LoadOnDemand, .Url* were then empty in the View.

I found a sensible answer that these elements are not getting serialized in the Telerik forum:
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/treeview/target-blank-on-treeviewitem-url.aspx#1548458

I solved it then, with adding a special

```
<span class="treeViewItemAddAjaxLocation"></span>
```

element to the *.Text* of the TreeViewItem. Locating these elements then via jQuery in the View and adding the desired html-attributes to the *< a >* element.

Telerik TreeView Binding method of the 2nd and 3rd stage elements via Ajax:

```
.DataBinding(databinding => databinding.Ajax().Select("_AjaxLoading", "Menu"))
```

Controller snippet in Action "_AjaxLoading":

```
IList<TreeViewItem> newNodes = new List<TreeViewItem>();
foreach (RevisionEntity revision in revisions)
{
    newNodes.Add(new TreeViewItem() 
    {
        Text = "Node Name" + "<span class='treeViewItemAddAjaxLocation'></span>", // name + locator element             
        Value = revision.ID.ToString() + ";RevisionEntity",
        Encoded = false,
        Enabled = true,
        LoadOnDemand = false,
        Url("/Menu/NavigateToRevisionDetails"), // creates an < a > element 
    });
}
return new JsonResult { Data = newNodes };
```

View:

```
<div class="t-bot">
    <a class="t-link t-in" href="/Menu/NavigateToRevisionDetails" data-ajax-update="#main" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax="true">Node Name
        <span class="treeViewItemAddAjaxLocation"></span>
    </a>
    <input class="t-input" type="hidden" value="774336a5-c6eb-42cc-905a-4d215c957fa2;RevisionEntity" name="itemValue">
</div>

function TreeView_onLoad(e) {
    var treeView = $(this).data("tTreeView");

    $(".treeViewItemAddAjaxLocation", treeView.element)
        .each(function () {
            var $this = $(this); // put it in jQuery constr
            item = $this.closest(".t-link"); // take the a
            item.attr('data-ajax-update', '#main');
            item.attr('data-ajax-mode', 'replace');
            item.attr('data-ajax-method', 'GET');
            item.attr('data-ajax', 'true');
            $this.remove(); // removes the span element
    });        
}
```

Result TreeView element:

```
<div class="t-bot">
    <a class="t-link t-in" href="/Menu/NavigateToRevisionDetails" data-ajax-update="#main" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax="true">Node Name</a>
    <input class="t-input" type="hidden" value="774336a5-c6eb-42cc-905a-4d215c957fa2;RevisionEntity" name="itemValue">
</div>
```

Loads the PartialView invoked through "NavigateToRevisionDetails" Action via Ajax in the #main html-element and the rest of the page doesn't get refreshed!